# Apt-get update not completing

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

Situation: Ubunutu 17.10.1 Installed (64 bit)
           Local Repository on different host

- Run `apt-get update`, which process the sources file that has the pointers to the local repository. Apt reports back that it is reading the package lists—succesfully.
- Apt reports error Some indes files failed to download. They have been ignored.
- When I look in the `/var/lib/apt/lists` directory is see the lock file but nothing else.
- When I look in the `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial` I see the package lists that were read from the local repository.

For some reason apt is either breaking out after the error or is completing but not moving the package lists files from the `/partial` to the `/lists` directory for use later. Any ideas on why this is failing? I have been fighting it for 4 days now.

Additional Information:

Environment is offline, but below are the last few lines of the output.

```
Err 29: http://repo.gaia.com/Ubuntu artful-security/main i386 Packages 404 Not Found
Ign:35 http://repo.gaia.com/Ubuntu artful-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:36 http://repo.gaia.com/Ubuntu artful-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:37 http://repo.gaia.com/Ubuntu artful-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Fetched 16.1 MB in 0s (17.2 MB/s)
Reading package lists .... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.gaia.com/Ubuntu/dists/artful/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.gaia.com/Ubuntu/dists/artful-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.gaia.com/Ubuntu/dists/artful-security/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please provide full command output.

Comment: Updated post with additional information.

Comment: See that 404 message? Try a different mirror.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after 4 days of fighting this I found an answer. I inserted the [arch=64] in front of the lines in the sources.list file. This caused apt to properly process the repo and move files where they needed to be. Wow this was painful.

I had thought that since this was a 64 bit OS it would be smart enough to process the repo for what it needed. Additionally I am not replicating the binary portions of the repo as I will not be recompiling anything.